# Replace a string with other one

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace a string "#security" with "security\n\tauthorization : enabled" in a file file.txt. Here \n represents a new line and \t for tab. How can I do this using sed command.

Comment: Seems like a homework question...

Comment: This is very basic. There's tons and tons of similar questions that has been asked , and there's tons and tons of resources for basic `sed` on google.  Do your research. We are not free "do my homework" service

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like homework

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/#security/security\n\tauthorization : enabled/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: `man sed`